# Docker Slow Response Time with Laravel API calls

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, docker

#### Docker Response Time

Does anyone have any idea why response time takes up to 1500 ms when using docker ?

[image: response time through docker]
[image: env through docker]

While when I run in my local machine it's only ~200 ms which's reasonable

[image: response time on local machine]
[image: env local machine]

my `docker-compose.yml` file

```yaml
version: "3.4"

networks:
    backend:
        driver: bridge

services:
  mysql:
    image: mysql:8.0
    container_name: mysql
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - 3307:3306
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=securerootpassword
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=${DB_DATABASE}
      - MYSQL_USER=${DB_USERNAME}
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=${DB_PASSWORD}
    networks:
      backend:
        aliases:
          - db-network

  app: 
    container_name: laravel_app
    build:
        context: .
        dockerfile: ./docker/8.0/php/Dockerfile
        args:
            WWWGROUP: '1000'
    ports:
        - '${APP_PORT:-80}:80'
    networks:
      backend:
        aliases:
          - laravel-app-network
    volumes:
        - '.:/var/www/html' # tried - '.:/var/www/html:cached' same results
    depends_on:
        - mysql
```

my `docker/8.0/php/Dockerfile`

```
FROM ubuntu:21.04

USER root

ARG WWWGROUP

WORKDIR /var/www/html

ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND noninteractive
ENV TZ=UTC

RUN ln -snf /usr/share/zoneinfo/$TZ /etc/localtime && echo $TZ > /etc/timezone

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
        libpng-dev \
        zlib1g-dev \
        libxml2-dev \
        libzip-dev \
        libonig-dev \
        zip \
        curl \
        unzip \
        webp \
        gnupg \
        gosu \
        ca-certificates \
        git \
        supervisor \
        libcap2-bin \
        python3

RUN mkdir -p ~/.gnupg \
        && chmod 600 ~/.gnupg \
        && echo "disable-ipv6" >> ~/.gnupg/dirmngr.conf \
        && apt-key adv --homedir ~/.gnupg --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys E5267A6C \
        && apt-key adv --homedir ~/.gnupg --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys C300EE8C

RUN echo "deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu hirsute main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ppa_ondrej_php.list \
       && curl -sS https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/pubkey.gpg | apt-key add - \
       && echo "deb https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/ stable main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/yarn.list \
       && curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_16.x | bash -

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y php8.0-cli php8.0-dev \
       php8.0-pgsql php8.0-sqlite3 php8.0-gd \
       php8.0-curl php8.0-memcached \
       php8.0-imap php8.0-mysql php8.0-mbstring \
       php8.0-xml php8.0-zip php8.0-bcmath php8.0-soap \
       php8.0-intl php8.0-readline php8.0-pcov \
       php8.0-msgpack php8.0-igbinary php8.0-ldap \
       php8.0-redis php8.0-swoole
       
RUN php -r "readfile('http://getcomposer.org/installer');" | php -- --install-dir=/usr/bin/ --filename=composer

RUN apt-get install -y nodejs \
        && npm install -g npm

RUN apt-get install -y mysql-client

RUN setcap "cap_net_bind_service=+ep" /usr/bin/php8.0

RUN groupadd --force -g $WWWGROUP sail
RUN useradd -ms /bin/bash --no-user-group -g $WWWGROUP -u 1337 sail

COPY ./docker/8.0/start-container /usr/local/bin/start-container
COPY ./docker/8.0/supervisord.conf /etc/supervisor/conf.d/supervisord.conf
COPY ./docker/8.0/php.ini /etc/php/8.0/cli/conf.d/99-sail.ini
RUN chmod +x /usr/local/bin/start-container

EXPOSE 80

ENTRYPOINT ["start-container"]
```

##### CPU Usage

Not to mention when on idle state it might take up to 3-4 seconds

Does it have to do with CPU usage ?

[image: cpu usage]

on an api call request it geos up to 17-20 % during the 1400 ms and back to 0.01%

> note taht it's modified `sail` Dockerfile provided by [Laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/sail)

the same issue consist if used sail out of the box

Also, I insured that all dependencies in Dockerfile are installed on my local machine, and still the same issue.

Comment: What does your `Dockerfile` build ? It depends a lot on what you have running there. Do you have any PHP plugins set that you did not set in your local machine but you did in Docker ?

Comment: I edited my question and added `Dockerfile`

Comment: well, I am not sure about sail, I tried using it when it came out but it has ton of garbage you will never use, to it takes a lot to build the image... it is way better to have your own `docker-compose` with each service instead of one image with all services inside...

Comment: I'm using `docker-compose` to build my containers, I tried some open-source libraries and still have the same issue.

Comment: What is taking 1500ms?

Comment: @rick-james api call response time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem Resolved:

It turned out to be windows/WSL related issue, that my development environment was built on windows running a Ubuntu 20.04 LTS `/mnt/c/Users/<username>/code-directory`

I migrated the entire code to the actual ubuntu absolute path `/var/www/html/code-directory` like in a production server and it's working perfectly. And made changes to `Dockerfile` accordingly.

Response time is ~100ms which's faster than localhost of windows OS 200ms

[image: response time]